# Two Same Measurement with Different Criteria

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, mdx

Goal:
The second measurement named "Reseller Order Count" (it is not applied yet in the list) shall be filtrated in the table based on Gender and Countries only.
The remaining of measurement namned "Reseller Order Count" and "Discount Amount" shall not be affected by Gender, it is only affected by "Countries".

Problem:
I do not know how to do it. I tried but failed.

Information:
*The Countries is applied in the data DataSet2.
*You use parameters to filtrate the value
*I'm using SSAS as a datasource
*The datasource is Adventurework DW2012 multi.
*You select the value as a parameter to make a filtration in the list.

[image]

```
WITH MEMBER 
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Employee].[Gender].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Employee].[Gender].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER 
    [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Employee].[Gender].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 

    SELECT 
    {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue], 
    [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
    } 
    ON COLUMNS , 

    [Employee].[Gender].CHILDREN ON ROWS 

FROM [Adventure Works]



WITH MEMBER 
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Geography].[Country].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Geography].[Country].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER 
    [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Geography].[Country].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 

    SELECT 
    {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
    [Measures].[ParameterValue], 
    [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
    } 
    ON COLUMNS , 

    [Geography].[Country].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 

FROM [Adventure Works]



SELECT
{ 
    [Measures].[Reseller Order Count], 
    [Measures].[Discount Amount] 
} ON COLUMNS, 
{ 
    ([Reseller].[Reseller Type].[Business Type].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT ( STRTOSET(@Countries, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [Adventure Works]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the code below to the source code above

```
WITH
SET Day
AS StrToSet (@Gender)

Member [Measures].[Measures].[Discount Amount - intakt]
AS Sum ( Day , [Measures].[Discount Amount] )
```

It fulfills the goal!